# What does count at the end of response mean in Postman?

Tags: testing, count, postman

I am starting out with Postman. I made a simple GET request and got a response. At the end of the response, is "count=14". I am trying to understand what count means here?
I thought the number of records in the response is 14, but its only 10. So what does count=14 mean? Thankyou for your response!
This is the response I got:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "074df210-e1fb-4298-9407-d97881dc1af2",
            "fullName": "Abcd",
            "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
            "phone": "112-112-112"

        },
        {
            "id": "4f0835d7-7c02-43da-86c7-77a03b4",
            "fullName": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "phone": "1234-234"
        },
        {
            "id": "a9e8cfb6-f62a-4a8e-84a5-df30",
            "fullName": "Kitty Doe",
            "email": "kittydoe@gmail.com",
            "phone": "123-493-892"
        },
        {
            "id": "319bdb34-e1c1-4e86-192",
            "fullName": "Lovely Doe",
            "email": "lovelydoe@gmail.com",
            "phone": "089-829-3898"

        },
        {
            "id": "1dfe5bba-e14b-4e9d-b90c",
            "fullName": "Memory Doe",
            "email": "memorydoe@gmail.com",
            "phone": "273-872-8398"
        },
        {
            "id": "61f466d5-ec00-76ccb88fff5e",
            "fullName": "asdas",
            "email": "asdas@gmail.com",
            "phone": "123-123-9231"

        },
        {
            "id": "f77b8e1d-70f2-4d44-b243-e61eac2a41a0",
            "fullName": "asdasda",
            "email": "asdasda@gmail.com",
            "phone": "123-123-1291"
           },

        {
            "id": "7d071c9e-fce6-4732-bed3-c18412a962c1",
            "fullName": "Monday",
            "email": "monday@gmail.com",
            "phone": "123-129-1231"
        },

        {
            "id": "5a1d1e9d-7396-41e3-aa96-864b",
            "fullName": "Tuesday",
            "email": "tuesday@gmail.com",
            "phone": "123-241-2534"

        },
        {
            "id": "f5da56d1-9fc2861e6da3",
            "fullName": "Wednesday",
            "email": "wednesday@gmail.com",
            "phone": "129-121-1212"

        }
    ],
    "count": 14
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the APIs creator or the Docs. That property could mean a number of different things in a number of different contexts.

Comment: Thanks Danny, I do have the api documentation but didnt find anything in it. Will lookup though and will post a answer if I find anything.